# constraint primary key value range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like the primary key to take character string value in the range 00000 to 99999. Any idea how I can write the constraint in MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE car_spares(
spare_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(15),
description VARCHAR(200),
PRIMARY KEY (spare_code)
)
```

Thanks

Comment: WHat DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On other platforms, you'd use a check constraint. But [MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You can use a trigger, or you can use a table and a foreign key reference.

For example

```
create table spare_codes (
  spare_code char(5) not null,
  primary key (spare_code)
);

insert into spare_codes values
('00000'), ('00001'), ... ('99999');
```

And then

```
CREATE TABLE car_spares(
  spare_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(15),
  description VARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (spare_code),
  foreign key (spare_code) references spare_codes (spare_code)
);
```

There are a lot of ways to generate those codes--spreadsheet, scripting languages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try *CHECK*, e.g.

```
create table car_spares(
  spare_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK ((spare_code  >= '00000') and (spare_code <= '99999')),
  ...
```

be careful, the exact syntax depends on database, for instance it could be

```
create table car_spares(
  spare_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT spare_code_cons CHECK ((spare_code  >= '00000') and (spare_code <= '99999'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
CREATE TABLE car_spares (
   spare_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT chkCode CHECK (sparecode >= '00000' AND sparecode <= '99999')
);
```